# What causes a parent container to cut off content in child element?

Tags: css, uiwebview, mobile-safari

On Mac Safari and Chrome, this dark select box appears correctly:

[image]

In iOS Safari, it gets cut off at the border of the selected div:

[image]

What could make that happen? Here are the styles of the selected parent:

[image]

and on the select box:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the parents of the select box had overflow-y hidden.