# How to force div to spill outside of ul container on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I let an arbitrary `div` nested within a `ul` spill outside of the `ul`, which is set to `width: 160px;` and `overflow-y: hidden;`? I have set it to `overflow-y: hidden` because the list needs to be scrollable.

Here is my list:

```
  <ul>
      <li> color name</li>
      <div class="tooltip">color name</div>
      <li> color name</li>
      <div class="tooltip">color name</div>
      <li> color name</li>
      <div class="tooltip">color name</div>
    .....
    </ul>
```

For the names whose text is wider than 160 pixels I want a hover event to reveal the tooltip element's text and I want this text to spill outside of its container, `ul`.

I have read the following resources but none of them have helped me:

- [Allow specific tag to override overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden/29687454#29687454)
- [Hovered element to overflow out from an overflow:hidden element css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446287/hovered-element-to-overflow-out-from-an-overflowhidden-element-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/
- [CSS spread <li> horizontally across <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131310/css-spread-li-horizontally-across-ul?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Why does inner DIV spills out of outer DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487863/why-does-inner-div-spills-out-of-outer-div?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent
- [What causes a parent container to cut off content in child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551733/what-causes-a-parent-container-to-cut-off-content-in-child-element)
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-pure-css-tooltips-3d5a3e237346

Comment: Could you provide the code you're referring to?

Comment: just curious why <div>'s are needed inside the <ul><li> structure here. I think you can accomplish your task just using jQuery. But would like to see working fiddle of your code to look for other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should fix your HTML. Only `LI` element can be direct children of `UL` elements. The invalid HTML is not likely to give you any issues in this particular case, but you should always strive to write valid HTML as you never know what weird issues might come up.

Next, if you have `overflow: hidden` on your parent `UL`, then there is nothing you can really do without getting javascript involved. Most "tooltip" types of libraries will handle this for you:

- On hover, make a copy of the DIV which is *outside* of the `UL` (preferable at the document root - a direct child of the `BODY`)
- Position the copied DIV so that it appears on top of (or next to) the original DIV - this requires JavaScript and I will leave as an exercise for the OP
- Delete the copy when the user is no longer hovering.

Again, most "tooltip" libraries already do this for you. You might have to write custom CSS to make a tooltip appear *on top of* and existing element as opposed to next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, the problem can be solved by applying the `z-index` property to an `::after` pseudo-element that receives content on `:hover`.

This creates a "tooltip" that's triggered by a hover state and will "spill out" of any parent div regardless of the parent's `overflow` property. As a bonus, it won't invalidate your markup with rogue tags in your lists.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">color</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.list {
  border: 1px solid black; //to see element boundary
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 160px;
}

.list-item::after {
  content: '';
}

.list-item:hover::after {
  background-color: gray; //aesthetic only
  content: 'long tooltip text about the color';
  margin-left: 5px; //aesthetic only
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/alaman/pen/mKrEVa?editors=1100)

Comment: +1 Though worth noting that this falls apart if the list get's `position: relative` added to it. It also happens to work, but I'd be cautious of browsers considering this a bug and changing its behavior in the future (don't have time to read the spec right now)

Comment: Good catch. It's not a bulletproof solution but (afaik) it's the best you can do in pure CSS. Like you said in your answer a javascript implementation (yay tooltip libraries!) would be much more robust.