# Hoverable Dropdown spilling out of UL

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists, dropdown

I'm trying to make a size-limited unordered list with hoverable dropdowns as list items that "spill" out of the unordered list.

I used this [W3 example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) and modified it in the following way. Notice how the hoverable dropdowns are being hidden within the <ul>.

```css
#menucontainer {
    display:none;
}.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 80;
  transform: translate(90px,-40px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#div1 {

}

#ul1 {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    /* margin-left: 41px; */
    padding: 0px;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#ul1:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div>
<ul id="ul1">
<li>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I were to remove the `position: relative` from the .dropdown class I would get the desired effect of the hoverable spilling out of the <ul> BUT it messes up it's position. You can see this on the 4th <li>.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/241fdxwo/2/) without `position:relative`

Is there any way to achieve this? I read all the 'Similar Questions' with only this one [How to force div to spill outside of ul container on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730452/how-to-force-div-to-spill-outside-of-ul-container-on-hover) being the closest in description to what I would like to do.

Any help or suggestions is much appreciate. Thank you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your issue as i couldn't reproduce it in the JS Fiddle. If I understand correctly I think you should remove the "overflow: hidden" from the #ul1 and the hover state classes. When i did it worked alright.

Comment: If I understand correctly:
1) If I remove `overflow:hidden` the unordered list STOPS being size limited.
2) I need the hover classes to make it a hoverable dropdown as appears in the W3 example.
3) With `position:relative` the position of the dropdown is correct but it is being cropped by the `overflow:hidden` property. Without the `position:relative` the dropdown appears correctly but its position is wrong.